# Why copy constructor is not called when returned value from overloaded operator is passed

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Consider the following scenario

```
class Integer
{
   long long n;
   public:
   Integer(long long i):n(i){}
   Integer(){cout<<"constructor";}
   void print()
   {
      cout<<n<<endl;
   }
   Integer(const Integer &a){cout<<"copy constructor"<<" "<<a.n<<endl;}
   Integer operator+(Integer b);
};

Integer Integer:: operator+(Integer b)
{
   this->n = this->n + b.n;
   return *this;
}
int main() 
{
   // your code goes here
   Integer a(5);
   Integer b(6);
   Integer c(a+b);//line 1
   return 0;
 }
```

If `a+b` was temporary then i understand that copy constructor would not be called. But `a+b` does not return a temporary.
The output i get is

```
 copy constructor 6  //this is because Integer object is passed as value to operator+
 copy constructor -5232903157125162015 //this is when object is returned by value from operator+
```

I think there should be one more call when `a+b` is used to initialize `c`. Most of the related questions have to do with return value optimization but `i` can't relate RVO to this.

Comment: Unrelated; Shouldn't you write `b.n += this->n; return b;`?

Comment: Off topic: `a+b` is kinda broken. It modifies `a` the way a += operator would.

Comment: `a+b` *does* return a temporary (since `operator+` returns by value) and the call is removed by *copy elision*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: You have undefined behaviour. You can't really reason a program with UB. At least, you can't use it as an example to illustrate something.

Comment: BTW the garbage in your output is because your copy constructor does not actually initialize `n`, it just displays the value it is supposed to copy

Answer (score 2):

You say *`a+b` does not return a temporary*. Wrong. `a+b` (even if it changes `a` which will certainly mislead an future reader...) returns a temporary copy of `a` because it is declared to return an `Integer` and not a reference (`Integer&`).

So here is what happens:

```
Integer a(5); // creates an integer from int 5
Integer b(6); // creates an integer from int 6

Integer c(a+b); /* first creates a temp using copy ctor from b
                   updates a
                   creates a temp copy of the result
                   should create an integer by copy of the result (elided)
                   destroys the temporary created from b
*/

return 0; // destroys c, b, a
```

BTW: you had forgotten to initialize `n` in your copy ctor - it should be:

```
Integer(const Integer &a):n(a.n) {cout<<"copy constructor"<<" "<<a.n<<endl;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are witnessing the [copy ellission](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) of the constructor.

> When a nameless temporary, not bound to any references, would be moved or copied into an object of the same type (ignoring top-level cv-qualification), the copy/move is omitted. When that temporary is constructed, it is constructed directly in the storage where it would otherwise be moved or copied to. When the nameless temporary is the argument of a return statement, this variant of copy elision is known as RVO, "return value optimization".

To view the expected output (not eliding of constructor) use `-fno-elide-constructors` option in `gcc`.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in my comment on your question `Integer:: operator+` is not quite right. Moreover as mentioned in other answers, your copy constructor doesn't do the initialization of member and thus causes undefined behaviuor.

Comment: It's not the reason of the bug.

Comment: Actually, it answers a part of the question. Please edit your answer, then I can remove my downvote.

Comment: @Caduchon The question is not about a bug. OP seems to think a bug is an OK means to illustrate a point.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the copy constructor never copies anything and the `+` operator isn't overloaded correctly. Additionally, the default constructor leaves the `Integer` class with an uninitialized member, which *may* cause undefined behaviors (not 100% on that one) which may be causing some issues.

So what happens is, because the copy constructors never actually copy a value to the `n` member of `*this`, the default constructor is called, and std::cout displays whatever is at the location of `n` of 'a.n'; which, if uninitialized, could be anything.

[This website](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~donnie/cs11/cpp/cpp-ops.html) from Caltech is good, if imperfect, reference for overloading operators.

Try this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Integer{
    long long n;
public:
    Integer(long long i):n(i){}
    //Integer(){cout<<"cosntructor";} //This creates an unitialized  instance of integer.

    Integer(){// Do this instead.
        n = 0;
        cout << "Constructor" << endl;
    }

    void print(){
        cout<<n<<endl;
    }
    //Integer(const Integer &a){cout<<"copy constructor"<<" "<<a.n<<endl;} // This isn't a copy contructor.

    Integer(const Integer &a){ //This is a copy contructor.
        this->n = a.n;
        cout << "Copy constructor" << " " << a.n << endl;
    }

    Integer& operator+=(const Integer &);
    Integer operator+(const Integer &);
};

Integer& Integer::operator+=(const Integer &b){ //Always overload incrementors/decrementors first, makes life easier.
    this->n = this->n + b.n;
    return *this;
}


Integer Integer:: operator+(const Integer &b){
     return Integer(*this)+=b.n; //Notice the use of overloaded incrementor inside the '+' operator.
}

int main(){
    // your code goes here
    Integer a(5);
    Integer b(6);
    Integer c(a+b);//line 1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear how you're answering the question. This might require some clarification.

Comment: `operator+` would be better off if you flipped `this` and `b` because you're modifying `this`: `return b.n += this->n;`

Comment: @juanchopanza Okay, I added some clarification.

Comment: @user4581301 That would inhibit NRVO. Better in two statements, finishing with `return b;`.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 I still can't see it, but maybe it is because the question is unclear.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah yes, but I don't want to return `*this`, I want to return a new Integer object with `*this` passed to the copy constructor, then incremented, using this website as a reference: http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~donnie/cs11/cpp/cpp-ops.html

Comment: @NonCreature0714 That reference seems to offer bad advice on a few things. I would ignore it.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ok, I'll take your word for it because your rep is WAY up there – but what specifically is bad? I'm always looking for a good learning opportunity.

Comment: @juanchopanza - I don't want to get too chatty, but yeah the original post could be cleaned up a little

Comment: `return Integer(*this)+=b.n;` inhibits return value optimization, resulting in needless copying. Also your `+=` should return a reference.

Comment: @juanchopanza point taken. Non, just spotted the extra copy construction. You're safe, but you have an extra construction. `b` was copied on the way in, so you might as well use it and not waste its construction.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah wait, if `b` is copied on the way in, `return b;` cannot be elided anyway (but if the argument is a temporary, the copy *into* `b` can.)

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the guidance, I'll update in a second

Comment: @user4581301 I think I just spotted the extra copy construction too, I'll update it where I think it's happening

Answer (score 0):

It has a correct number of copy ctor calls:

1st is for `b` because `operator+(Integer b)` accepts `Integer` by value.

2nd is for `c` created by `operator+` result.

By the standard there could be a 3rd call: `return *this` might have created a temporary which would later be copied to `c`. But in reality it is always elided. You can turn off this elision in gcc&clang and you can't turn it off in MSVC.